Intellij is degraded to previous version, so getting Undefined step reference issue on feature files
Intellij is degraded to previous version, so getting Undefined step reference issue on feature files
Tried uninstalling and reinstalling cucumber and gherkin plugins, tried rebuilding the project and invalidating caches. Current version is 232.

Please provide more details of the issue, just in case this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858662/undefined-step-definitions-in-intellij
